# How to delete a folder or a file from usr/bin in linux/fedora

Tags: linux, fedora

I am using fedora ,

Unfortunately i had downloaded a package(for example 'selenium' or 'chrome') in the bin folder.
But i don't want that package in the bin folder, i want to remove it from the folder, i am unable do it manually as well as from the the terminal, so can anyone let me know how to delete a package from bin folder.

Actually i am trying to download a package as below from terminal

```
svn checkout http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ selenium- 
read-only
```

But i didn't see my path in terminal when i am downloading i.e., `usr/bin` , so the package has been downloaded in bin folder now.
Please help me out through this.

Comment: Do you know about `sudo` and `rm -rf` commands? Learn more about them and use them carefully (mistakes won't be easy to repair).

Comment: Did you do `svn checkout` while you were root? Because non-root users usually cannot even write to `/usr/bin`. Anyway, never do regular stuff as root.

Comment: @ArjunShankar: yes i was root at that time

Comment: @Kouripm - Well, then fix the problem after you read about the commands Basile has pointed out. And next time onwards, don't do anything as root, unless being root is absolutely necessary. Saves a lot of pain.

Comment: Thanks for u r help i tried Basile Starynkevitch command and that worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the /usr/bin folder is a protected folder which usually root user have full access to it
so if you want to make a change in it you should have a full access which can gain by "su" or "sudo" commands
try these commands on your terminal

```
su
<type your root password>
cd /usr/bin
rm <your special file names you want to remove>
```

you can do it by sudo too

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo rm <your special file names you want to remove>
<type your root password>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have privileges of deleting a file or folder in the /usr/ directory unless you are the root user. Therefore you can do that by right-clicking on the /usr/ directory and **Open as root**. This gives you the rights of the root in that directory.